# The best way to use self in function

Tags: python, function, class, self

For example I have the  following code:

```
class printconct:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a
    
    def run1(self):
        print(self.a)
        
    def run2(self):
        a = self.a
        print(a)

a = printconct("a")
a.run1()
a.run2()
```

Is there any different between `run1` and `run2` function? I know that both of them have the same result, may question is there any cases that it's better to use `run1` and other for `run2`. For example if I'm using variable `a` many time it's better to use `run2` etc.

Comment: In this case it is equivalent, but in a more complicated example it wouldn't necessarily be equivalent. I'm not really sure on your criteria for "better" here.

Comment: better fom memory, better for run time, etc. In other words in which case I should use each one of them?

Comment: Memory/runtime would be essentially the same. it is slightly faster to avoid the attribute lookup, but this is a micro-optimization that is usually not relevant

Answer (score 2):

Well, try it yourself

```py
class printconct:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a=a

    def run1(self):
        s=0
        for i in range(10000000):
            s+=self.a+self.a+self.a+self.a+self.a
        return s

    def run2(self):
        s=0
        a=self.a
        for i in range(10000000):
            s+=a+a+a+a+a
        return s
```

On my computer, there is a factor 2 in computation time (run2 is twice faster).

Note that

1. I had to introduce a for loop so that timing measurement, or method call is negligible in the total timing
2. Use several times the variable inside the for loop, so that the for loop itself stay negligible

So, yes, using a is twice as fast as using self.a.

But, also, I had to work to get into situation where it really matters.

The call for the method itself takes more time.  Plus, obviously, by saying `a=self.a` and then use `a` only once, well, you gain nothing (and loose even some) because you used `self.a` (doing `a=self.a`) to spare only one usage of `self.a`.

Comment: Thanks, it's part of what I'm looking for, but I what to know in more general, not only  the run time.

Answer (score 1):

```
def run1(self):
    print(self.a)
    
def run2(self):
    a = self.a
    print(a)
```

just noting that python is pass-by-object-reference.
For run1, you would be referencing an existing variable. No additional memory is allocated. For run2, if self.a is an immutable object:

```
 a = self.a
```

will allocate more memory for local variable 'a' and create a copy of self.a.