# Speeding up my python program (log analyzer)

Tags: python, logging, optimization

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys
from collections import Counter
from datetime import datetime


class LogEntryProcessor:
    def __init__(self, log_line):
        self.log_line = log_line

    def safe_extraction(self, extraction_function):
        try:
            return extraction_function()
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error during extraction: {e}")
            print(self.log_line)
            return None

    def extract_client(self):
        return self.safe_extraction(lambda: self.log_line.split(" ")[0])

    def extract_browser(self):
        return self.safe_extraction(lambda: self.log_line.split('"')[-2])

    def extract_method(self):
        return self.safe_extraction(lambda: self.log_line.split('"')[1].split()[0])

    def extract_page(self):
        return self.safe_extraction(lambda: self.log_line.split(" ")[6])

    def extract_response_time(self):
        return self.safe_extraction(lambda: int(self.log_line.split()[-1]))

    def extract_datetime(self):
        return self.safe_extraction(lambda: datetime.strptime(
            self.log_line.split("[")[1].split("]")[0].strip(), "%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S %z"
        ))


class LogStat:
    def __init__(self):
        self.statistics = {
            'FastestPage': None,
            'MostActiveClient': None,
            'MostActiveClientByDay': {},
            'MostPopularBrowser': None,
            'MostPopularPage': None,
            'SlowestAveragePage': None,
            'SlowestPage': None
        }
        self.page_response_times = Counter()
        self.client_by_day = {}
        self.popular_browsers = Counter()
        self.popular_pages = Counter()
        self.most_active_client = Counter()

    def add_line(self, line):
        entry_processor = LogEntryProcessor(line)
        if line == "" or entry_processor.extract_method() == "OPTIONS": return
        entry = {'client': entry_processor.extract_client(),
                 'browser': entry_processor.extract_browser(),
                 'page': entry_processor.extract_page(),
                 'datetime': entry_processor.extract_datetime(),
                 'response_time': entry_processor.extract_response_time()
                 }
        # Fastest page
        if self.statistics['FastestPage'] is None or entry['response_time'] <= self.statistics['FastestPage'][1]:
            self.statistics['FastestPage'] = (entry['page'], entry['response_time'])

        # Slowest page
        if self.statistics['SlowestPage'] is None or entry['response_time'] >= self.statistics['SlowestPage'][1]:
            self.statistics['SlowestPage'] = (entry['page'], entry['response_time'])

        # Slowest average page
        page = entry['page']
        response_time = entry['response_time']
        self.page_response_times[page] += response_time

        # Most active client by day
        date = entry['datetime'].strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
        date_object = datetime.strptime(date, "%Y-%m-%d").date()

        if date_object not in self.statistics['MostActiveClientByDay']:
            self.statistics['MostActiveClientByDay'][date_object] = Counter()

        self.statistics['MostActiveClientByDay'][date_object][entry['client']] += 1
        # Most popular browser
        self.popular_browsers[entry['browser']] += 1

        # Most popular page
        self.popular_pages[entry['page']] += 1
        # Most active client
        self.most_active_client[entry['client']] += 1

    def results(self):

        # Most popular browser
        most_popular_browser = [browser for browser, count in self.popular_browsers.most_common()
                                if count == self.popular_browsers.most_common(1)[0][1]]
        self.statistics['MostPopularBrowser'] = min(most_popular_browser)

        # Most popular page
        most_popular_pages = [page for page, count in self.popular_pages.most_common() if
                              count == self.popular_pages.most_common(1)[0][1]]
        self.statistics['MostPopularPage'] = min(most_popular_pages)

        # Most active client
        most_active_clients = [client for client, count in self.most_active_client.most_common() if
                               count == self.most_active_client.most_common(1)[0][1]]
        self.statistics['MostActiveClient'] = min(most_active_clients)

        # Calculate slowest average page
        avg_times = {page: total_time / self.popular_pages[page] for page, total_time in
                     self.page_response_times.items()}
        self.statistics['SlowestAveragePage'] = max(avg_times, key=avg_times.get)

        # Calculate most active client by day
        for date in self.statistics['MostActiveClientByDay']:
            most_popular_clients = [client for client, count in
                                    self.statistics['MostActiveClientByDay'][date].most_common() if
                                    count == self.statistics['MostActiveClientByDay'][date].most_common(1)[0][1]]
            self.statistics['MostActiveClientByDay'][date] = min(most_popular_clients)

        self.statistics['FastestPage'] = self.statistics['FastestPage'][0]
        self.statistics['SlowestPage'] = self.statistics['SlowestPage'][0]

        self.print_full_stats()
        return self.statistics

    def print_full_stats(self):
        print(f"FastestPage: {self.statistics['FastestPage']}")
        print(f"MostActiveClient: {self.statistics['MostActiveClient']}")
        print("MostActiveClientByDay:")
        for date, client in self.statistics['MostActiveClientByDay'].items():
            print(f"  {date}: {client}")
        print(f"MostPopularBrowser: {self.statistics['MostPopularBrowser']}")
        print(f"MostPopularPage: {self.statistics['MostPopularPage']}")
        print(f"SlowestAveragePage: {self.statistics['SlowestAveragePage']}")
        print(f"SlowestPage: {self.statistics['SlowestPage']}")


class LogStatFromFile:
    def __init__(self):
        self.log_stat = LogStat()

    def read_log_file(self, log_file):
        with open(log_file, 'r', encoding='cp437') as file:
            for line in file:
                yield line

    def process_log_file(self, log_file):
        for line in self.read_log_file(log_file):
            self.log_stat.add_line(line)

        return self.log_stat.results()


def make_stat():
    return LogStat()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len(sys.argv) > 1:
        LogStatFromFile().process_log_file(sys.argv[1])
```

So I have my program here.

`LogStat.add_line()` method adds a new log entry to update local variables and calculate the statistics.
`LogStat.results()` method calculates the total results and calculates the statistics.
`LogEntryProcessor` is for extracting different data from the log entry.

I have to analyze a large log file (59 GB).
I would be glad to have some pointers and tips on how to optimize my code, what I did wrong, etc.

I'm using a generator to read the file, I'm trying to use built-in structures like Counter.

```
20000    0.258    0.000    0.432    0.000 _strptime.py:309(_strptime)
20000    0.014    0.000    0.552    0.000 {built-in method strptime}
10000    0.005    0.000    0.364    0.000 hw4.py:34(extract_datetime)
```

It seems like the extraction of data from log entry takes a long time, especially `strptime`. I wonder if regex would be faster?

NEW_EDIT:
A log entry looks like this:

```
192.168.12.155 - - [08/Jul/2012:06:34:47 +0600] "GET /img/group.png HTTP/1.1" 304 189 "http://callider/menu-top.php" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; Tablet PC 2.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; InfoPath.3; MS-RTC LM 8)" 149
```

I also modified LogEntryProcessor like this:

```
class LogEntryProcessor:
def __init__(self, log_line):
    self.log_line = log_line
    self.log_line_split_space = log_line.split(" ")
    self.log_line_split_quote = log_line.split('"')

def extract_data(self):
    try:
        client = self.log_line_split_space[0]

        browser = self.log_line_split_quote[-2]

        page = self.log_line_split_space[6]

        response_time = int(self.log_line.split()[-1])

        datetime_str = search(r'\[([^]]+)\]', self.log_line).group(1)
        datetime_obj = datetime.strptime(datetime_str, "%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S %z")
        datetime_date = datetime_obj.date()

        return client, browser, page, response_time, datetime_date

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error during extraction: {e}")
        print(self.log_line)
        return None, None, None, None, None

def extract_method(self):
    try:
        method = self.log_line_split_quote[1].split()[0]
        return method
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error during extraction: {e}")
        print(self.log_line)
        return None
```

Now I wonder how it could be optimised further.
Only methods `extract_data` and `add_line` require optimisation since they are the ones being called millions of times when we read the logs.

Comment: you are doing the right things. is there something specific that is causing a problem ?

Comment: If you profile your code, and see what functions are being used the most what are things that are being used the most?

Comment: small optimization: Use `log_line.split(" ", 1)[0]` and similar to avoid redundant splits

Comment: it seems like extraction functions are eating up the time... maybe regex would be faster?

Comment: You parse the same line multiple times. A regex is definitely the way to go since it would allow you to capture all parts in one operation

Comment: Also, what's up with your creation of `date_object`? You `strptime` a part of your log. Then you turn this into a new string with `strftime` only to `strptime` it again to get the date. Huh? What problem exactly is this solving?

Comment: I fixed the dates, I think, @Homer512

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somethings that may improve your program runtime (though you should profile your code to see where areas for improvement can be made):

1. In `LogEntryProcessor()`

Each call to `self.safe_extraction()` involves some string manipulation which is duplicated in consecutive calls. Possibly instead of doing         `self.log_line.split()` or `self.log_line.split(" ")` you could just have a class variable that you can index the list from.

2. In `extract_datetime()`

You could use regex to try to find the date that you are looking for (sorry cannot help with what regex formula to use as I don't know what the datetime element looks like). If you want to maintain the current method, it may be faster to search for the first set of brackets using `.find()`, and do list slicing based on those indexes for the date.

3. Using `self.` in longer functions

Based on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73886239/the-best-way-to-use-self-in-function) using `self.` can be slower in functions where it is used a lot. So possibly in `add_line()` you could bring `self.statistics` into a local variable to make changes and then return that local copy.

4. Using `n` functions inside functions.

So doing:

```
most_popular_pages = [page for page, count in self.popular_pages.most_common() if count == self.popular_pages.most_common(1)[0][1]]
```

is trying to find `.most_common()` twice. First for when it loops through the items in the for loop. Second when it is being used in the `if` comparison. To improve this runtime you should do the following:

```
specific_popular_page = self.popular_pages.most_common(1)[0][1]
most_popular_pages = [page for page, count in self.popular_pages.most_common() if count == specific_popular_page]
```

`self.popular_browsers.most_common(1)[0][1]` should instead be a variable outside of the loop that is referenced instead of trying to find the static answer when you run through the loop.

These are just some initial suggestions.

Comment: Thanks, I've modified the LogEntryProcessor according to your advice (edited the question to provide the new version)

Comment: @Ruslanci what is the datetime object that you are trying to get (in what format)? If the default of `.split()` is any white space wouldn't you still get the same answer with `.split(" ")` in `int(self.log_line.split()[-1])`? (if so you can substitute that split with the list lookup that you already have)